# TreeView control - Is it possible to collapse w/o a postback?

Tags: asp.net, treeview, postback, callback, client-side-scripting

Everything i found online so far is very confusing about TreeView. I know it has a built-in callback, that developer can populate nodes from server on demand, etc etc.

I understand the populate node on demand - nodes populated from the server on demand (expand) works with the callback - and doesn't refresh the whole page - but it still goes to the server to get these nodes even though it is seemless.

But what I don't know/understand is whether it's possible to collapse the brach w/o callback or postback. Logically, why would I need to go to the server to collapse nodes - unless it is to update the control state?

In other words, does TreeView come with ANY client side events wired-up??? (i couldn't find any) or is it purely a server side control where the only think i can do to appear seemless is use callback feature.

I am using asp.net 3.5/c#

Answer (score 1):

Please check this out: [Client Side Expand/Collapse All Nodes For ASP.NET 2.0 Treeview](http://pushpontech.blogspot.com/2007/06/client-side-expandcollapse-all-nodes.html)